# Unity - No Particle Effect on GetKeyDown

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to complete one of the bonus problems for the 4th Challenge from Unity's Junior Programmer Create with Code 2 Pathway. The instructions are "The player should get a speed boost whenever the player presses spacebar - and a particle effect should appear when they use it". The hint is "In PlayerController, add a simple if-statement that adds an “impulse” force if spacebar is pressed. To add a particle effect, first attach it as a child object of the Focal Point."

I've added the speed boost successfully, but can't get the particle effect to work. I've attached the effect to be a child of the Focal Point, but nothing seems to be working. Here is my code below.

```
    private Rigidbody playerRb;
    public float speed = 500f;
    private GameObject focalPoint;

    private float speedBoost = 10.0f;

    public ParticleSystem smokeParticle;
    
    void Start()
    {
        playerRb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        focalPoint = GameObject.Find("Focal Point");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Add force to player in direction of the focal point (and camera)
        float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
        playerRb.AddForce(focalPoint.transform.forward * verticalInput * speed * Time.deltaTime); 

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            playerRb.AddForce(focalPoint.transform.forward * speedBoost, ForceMode.Impulse);

            smokeParticle.Play();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is the particle object in view? are you sure its not just off screen?

Comment: it's in view, if i set it to stay awake it'll play

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try `smokeParticle.Play(true);` most particle have children need to be played along with it

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ParticleSystem.Play.html